# How can we use validation controls in Webmatrix?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webmatrix

I am new to webmatrix, and trying to find how can i use validation controls like we use in asp.net in visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written an article on using Validation Helpers in Web Pages 2 here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/191/Validation-In-Razor-Web-Pages-2

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

WebMatrix 2 significantly improved the validation support.  Here's the official Microsoft link:  http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/whats-new/top-features-in-web-pages-2#validation.  Also, @MikeDotNetting has a short description as part of an HTML5 page:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/199/HTML5-Form-Helpers-For-WebMatrix.  MikeDotNetting is the independent authority on WebMatrix.